# Embedding a hidden hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I know almost nothing about html, but I would like to make a static html page with links to many streaming video sites.  And when the user clicks the link, he/she is redirected to the site but when the mouse is moved a link would appear at the top of the streaming video site allowing the user to navigate back to the original html page. Can someone point me to a tutorial that explains how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off displaying the streaming site inside of an iframe and not navigating away from your page. You can then use styling to display the iframe and the rest of your links however you want.

Comment: I'd note that this won't be possible in a lot of cases - plenty of sites forbid framing via X-Frame-Options headers or frame breaking JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Would like to see some code for an attempt at this but I highly recommend you look into **anchors** for HTML and also understand the difference between **relative** and **absolute** paths. Guide for it is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

**Example of a anchor in action:**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"></a> //path to the url of google.
```

Comment: Can you explain? the user asked about clicking on a link and it going to another page. This involves anchors? Don't understand how this is missing the point

Comment: You didn't see the "a link would appear at the top of the streaming video site allowing the user to navigate back to the original html page" bit?

Comment: Over exaggeration of "missing the question massively" when it's going to require `href` whether it be for HTML or JavaScript to allow the user to go to another page and redirected back to the original page.

Comment: Explaining how to make an A tag is like answering "How do I cook a beef Wellington?" with "You will need an oven!" and leaving it at that. OP wants to do something much more complex than a simple link, and likely knows how to write `<a href=""></a>` already.